# Браузер определяет картинку как text/html

Tags: php, .htaccess

Зметил что при загрузке страницы, у меня в консоле разработчика пишет на картики с расширением ".jpg" - тип: text/html, и из-за этого при каждом реологе страницы - запрашивает её с сервера, и приходит она со статусом 200, вместо 304. И идет лишний трафик.

Файл .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# не позволять httpd отдавать файлы, начинающиеся с точки (.htaccess,     .svn,     .git и прочие)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# если директория или файл существуют, использовать их напрямую
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# иначе отправлять запрос на файл index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Как видно, в файле нет ничего (на мой взгляд) что заставляет с таким расширением определять как text/html.

Вопрос:
Как можно через .htaccess, или другими способами принудительно устанавливать тип для .jpg ( и других расширений ) нужный тип?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в .htaccess

```
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe
```